# How can I repair the chuck on my cordless drill?

Tags: drill

I have a cordless drill, over the years the chuck has moved further away from the body of the drill, opening up a large gap. It no longer fits in my toolbox!

[image]
<sup>Black and Decker KC1282F Cordless Drill</sup>

How are these keyless chucks attached? Can I remove and re-attach the chuck so that it sits flush with the body of the drill?

---

Update:

I tried the method in Hightower's answer, which, it is now clear, is the correct procedure.

However the screw appeared to be a Torx screwhead. Here's what happened when I tried to turn it clockwise (by hand, using a normal sized screwdriver) ...

[image]

:-(

I may have to buy a suitable bit for an impact driver. Or wait for the chuck to fall off whilst I am drilling. Or just buy a new drill.

Comment: Put a block of wood, say 2x4, on a table. Open the chuck wide open so the jaws are recessed. Then hammer the chuck down onto the wood. Check your progress to see if its working. And don't hit it so hard you damage the drill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chuck will most likely not be press fitted onto the shaft, meaning that hammering will not work to get the gap away.

the chuck actually screws onto the drill shaft (reverse thread -  counter-clockwise to tighten) So what you need to do is the following:

1. Open the chuck fully, and look into the chuck opening - can you see a screw or Allen key? ... if so, remove the screw/bolt.
2. get one of your biggest Allen/hex keys and insert into the chuck (short side first) and tighten the chuck jaws around the key.
3. Turn the key clockwise until the chuck jaws are back to the original position.
4. Replace the screw/bolt.

if you cannot turn, you may want to place the drill on a hard surface and knock the key with a hammer a few times to see if it turns.